# Assign priority to nodejs tasks in a event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

Is there any way by which one can apply priority to Node.js task's in a event loop.
I want to assign priority to task which are present in a event loop of nodejs.

Suppose in a event loop there are 5 jobs A,B,C,D,E which having same priority and then next job is received whose priority is higher than last five jobs. Then event loop starts executing that higher priority job.

Comment: A code example would help.

Comment: Added example please check it.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @neelsg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_priority_scheduling is a well-known problem with lots of applications

Comment: Actually in my application multiple functions' are executing parallelly i.e in a event loop. So if there are some important high priority functions are there so I want these functions to be executed first and then other.

Comment: @Bergi I'm aware that this is a well known problem, but don't think it is possible to do in Node.js. Sometimes you can avoid such issues by re-factoring a problem. If the asker has some specific reason why he/she needs to do this, we may be able to suggest a different approach.

Comment: @Sanket Could it be possible for you to move the high priority functions to a dedicated **[Child Process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)**?

Comment: No if I did so then it will giving problem in a database CURD operations.

Comment: @neelsg: Well, you can always write your own scheduler :-) With generators/continuations this should be quite possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event loop in [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) does not support priorities. See some documentation:

- http://nodejs.org/api/events.html
- http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-event-loop/

Short of rewriting it, I don't think there is much you can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a priority queue, something like [priorityqueuejs](https://github.com/janogonzalez/priorityqueuejs)

In this way you can dequeue an item with the max priority and execute it.

Some code:

```
'use strict';

var PriorityQueue = require('priorityqueuejs');

var queue = new PriorityQueue(function(a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
});

queue.enq({ value: 10, func: function() { console.log("PRIORITY: 10"); } });
queue.enq({ value: 500, func: function() { console.log("PRIORITY: 500"); } });
queue.enq({ value: 300, func: function() { console.log("PRIORITY: 300"); } });
queue.enq({ value: 100, func: function() { console.log("PRIORITY: 100"); } });

(function executeNext() {
  if(queue.size()) {
    var next = queue.deq();
    next.func();
    if(queue.size()) {
      setTimeout(executeNext, 0);
    }
  }
})();
```

And the output is:

```
PRIORITY: 500
PRIORITY: 300
PRIORITY: 100
PRIORITY: 10
```

Here is the `executeNext` function extracts the next top-priority item and executes it.